# Modify existing column in multiple csv files

Tags: csv, powershell

I have multiple csv files where Column 0 needs to be modified.

Currently it is in this format:

```
Header 1, ...
0, ...
0, ...
0, ...
...
```

Instead I would like to go through each csv file and change it to this format(incrementing by 1 each time):

```
Header 1, ...
0, ...
1, ...
2, ...
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Import-Csv](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113341) cmdlet to import your csv, iterate over each item using the [ForEach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet to increment the item, and finally export it back using [Export-Csv](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113299).

```
Import-Csv 'YOUR_CSV_PATH' | 
    ForEach-Object -Begin{ $i = 1} -Process { $_.'Header 1' = $i++; $_ } |
    Export-Csv 'YOUR_CSV_PATH2' -NoTypeInformation
```